# jquery select2 - getting the individual id of a multiple selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 in a conttentflow type image gallery and I have a callback that moves the image gallery image to the id of the selection in the drop down. It works well when I don't set multiple to true but fails if true. I'm hoping for help in getting the individual id of each multiple selection.

```
    function format(state) {
        return "<img class=\"mini\" src=\"" + state.icon + "\"/>" + " "  +  state.value + "<strong> " + state.keyword + "</strong>";
}
         
$("#select").select2({
        data:function() { return { text:'label', results: data }; },
        formatSelection: format,
    formatResult: format,
    width: 220,
    placeholder:"Search Images",
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
    allowClear: true,
    multiple:true
    }).on("change", function(e) {
        var move = $("#select").select2("val");
        cf.moveTo(move);                    
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation, the following code works:

```
$("#select").select2({
        data:function() { return { text:'label', results: data }; },
        formatSelection: format,
    formatResult: format,
    width: 220,
    placeholder:"Search Images",
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
    allowClear: true,
    multiple:true
    }).on("change", function(e) {
        var move = $("#select").select2("val");
                    var lastE = move.slice(-1)[0];
        cf.moveTo(lastE);       
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

when multiple is set to true the val will contain a comma separated list of values, so

```
    var move = $("#select").select2("val").split(",");
```

now move will contain an array of selected ids.

Comment: I get "split is not a function" in firebug

Comment: var v=$("#selet").select2("val"); if (v) { var move=v.split(","); } else {... handle empty selection }

Comment: Still get the error, v.split not a function. This works though:

`var move = $("#select").select2("val");

var lastE = move.slice(-1)[0];

   cf.moveTo(lastE);`

Answer (score 0):

The values are an array and you may use like this:

```
var values = $("#select").select2("val").join(",");
```